# Did the castle's enchanted staff gain magical powers after the curse?

Tags: plot-explanation, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In *Beauty and the Beast* (2017) the castle's enchanted staff welcomes Belle for dinner in a great **fantasy** way. I just can't describe it. It can be achieved with fantasy powers only.

Did the castle's enchanted staff gain magical powers after the curse?

Answer (score 1):

The cursed people turned castle objects are magical to begin with. No additional supernatural powers have been detected to my knowledge. Although, I do notice some interesting scenes throughout the movie that provoke that way of thinking. Chip uses his saucer as some sort of surfboard that help him maneuver around. Lumiere can relight himself.

The feather-duster lady can fly... I do see what you are saying, but I do not think those things are considered powers exactly.

Comment: If the staff didn't have these abilities, then they'd just be stuck sitting around collecting dust.

Comment: Yeah, although they wouldn't be able to "live" forever. Once the last petal fell, they would turn into average pieces of junk.